# How to reduce the greediness of a regular expression in AWK?

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I want to do non-greedy pattern (regular expression) matching in `awk`. 
Here is an example:

```
echo "@article{gjn, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " | awk '{ sub(/@.*,/,""); print }'
```

Is it possible to write a regular expression that selects the shorter string?

```
@article{gjn,
```

instead of this long string?:

```
@article{gjn, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
```

I want to get this result:

```
 Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
```

---

I have another example:

```
echo ",article{gjn, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " | awk '{ sub(/,[^,]*,/,""); print }'
      ↑                                                              ↑^^^^^
```

Note that I changed the `@` characters to comma (`,`) characters
in the first position of both the input string and the regular expression
(and also changed `.*` to `[^,]*`). 
Is it possible to write a regular expression that selects the shorter string?

```
, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
```

instead of the longer string?:

```
,article{gjn, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
```

I want to get this result:

```
,article{gjn
```

Comment: Just as regex are inadequate for robust HTML parsing, they probably won't be able to do this kind of context-sensitive grammar parsing.  However, if your set of inputs is fairly restricted and well-formed, you may be able to get away with regex as long as you declare what your restrictions are.  For example you could look for `Author` following a comma and whitespace, followed by whitespace followed by `=` followed by whitespace followed by `{` followed by any non-`}` followed by `}`, although this requires (among other things) that you can't nest `{}` inside the `= { ... }` part.

Comment: @jw013, thank you for your explanation. Yet I will wait for suggestions of other users.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to select `@` and up to the first `,` after that, you need to specify it as `@[^,]*,`

That is `@` followed by any number (`*`) of non-commas (`[^,]`) followed by a comma (`,`).

That approach works as the equivalent of `@.*?,`, but not for things like `@.*?string`, that is where what's after is more than a single character. Negating a character is easy, but [negating strings in regexps is a lot more  difficult](/a/319175).

A different approach is to pre-process your input to replace or prepend the `string` with a character that otherwise doesn't occur in your input:

```
gsub(/string/, "\1&") # pre-process
gsub(/@[^\1]*\1string/, "")
gsub(/\1/, "") # revert the pre-processing
```

If you can't guarantee that the input won't contain your replacement character (`\1` above), one approach is to use an escaping mechanism:

```
gsub(/\1/, "\1\3") # use \1 as the escape character and escape itself as \1\3
                   # in case it's present in the input
gsub(/\2/, "\1\4") # use \2 as our maker character and escape it
                   # as \1\4 in case it's present in the input
gsub(/string/, "\2&") # mark the "string" occurrences

gsub(/@[^\2]*\2string/, "")

# then roll back the marking and escaping
gsub(/\2/, "")
gsub(/\1\4/, "\2")
gsub(/\1\3/, "\1")
```

That works for fixed `string`s but not for arbitrary regexps like for the equivalent of `@.*?foo.bar`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the good response.
In my editing I asked yet another example (see my edit).

Answer (score 6):

There are already several good answers providing work-arounds for `awk`'s inability to do non-greedy matches, so I'm providing some information on an alternative way to do it using [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/) (PCRE).  Note that most simple "match and print" `awk` scripts can easily be re-implemented in `perl` using the `-n` command-line option, and more complex scripts can be converted with the [a2p](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::a2p) Awk to Perl translator.

[Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) has a non-greedy operator which can be used in Perl scripts and anything that uses PCRE. For example, also implemented in GNU grep's `-P` option.

PCRE is [not identical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE#Differences_from_Perl) to Perl's regular expressions, but it is very close. It is a popular choice of a regular expression library for many programs, because it's very fast, and the Perl enhancements to extended regular expressions are very useful.

From the [perlre(1)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) man page:

```
   By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will match
   as many times as possible (given a particular starting location) while
   still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.  If you want it to
   match the minimum number of times possible, follow the quantifier with
   a "?".  Note that the meanings don't change, just the "greediness":

       *?        Match 0 or more times, not greedily
       +?        Match 1 or more times, not greedily
       ??        Match 0 or 1 time, not greedily
       {n}?      Match exactly n times, not greedily (redundant)
       {n,}?     Match at least n times, not greedily
       {n,m}?    Match at least n but not more than m times, not greedily
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post, but the following information might be useful for others.

There is a way, admittedly crude, to perform non-greedy RE matching in awk.  The basic idea is to use the match(string, RE) function, and progressively reduce the size of the string until the match fails, something like (untested):

```
if (match(string, RE)) {
    rstart = RSTART
    for (i=RLENGTH; i>=1; i--)
        if (!(match(substr(string,1,rstart+i-1), RE))) break;
    # At this point, the non-greedy match will start at rstart
    #  for a length of i+1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For general expressions, this can be used as a non-greedy match:

```
function smatch(s, r) {
    if (match(s, r)) {
        m = RSTART
        do {
            n = RLENGTH
        } while (match(substr(s, m, n - 1), r))
        RSTART = m
        RLENGTH = n
        return RSTART
    } else return 0
}
```

I'm using this based on @JimMellander's answer. `smatch` behaves like `match`, returning:

> the  position  in  `s`  where  the  regular expression `r` occurs, or 0 if it does not. The variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` are set to the position and length of the matched string.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way in awk to do non-greedy matching. You may be able to get the desired output, though. sch's suggestion will work for that line. If you can't rely on a comma, but "Author" is always the start of the what you want, you could do this:

```
awk '{ sub(/@.*Author/,"Author"); print }'
```

If the number of characters preceding Author is always the same, you could do this:

```
awk '{ sub(/@.{21}/,""); print }'
```

You just need to know what your data looks like across the whole set.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way. The given problem can be solved fairly easily by using commas as separator.

```
echo "@article{gjn2010jucs, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " |
awk -F, '{sub(/^[ \t]/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

When the numbers of fields vary something slightly better is usually needed. In such case finding a stop words often pays off, as you can cut anything out from the line by using them. Within context of the example here's what I mean by stop words.

```
echo "@article{gjn2010jucs, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa}, " |
awk  '{sub(/.*Author/, "Author", $0); sub(/},.*/, "}", $0); print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post . But here is something just using awk as OP as requested:
A=@article{gjn2010jucs, Author =   {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},
echo $A |awk 'sub(/@[^,]*/,"")'

Output:
, Author = {Grzegorz J. Nalepa},

Comment: That answer is wrong  for about five reasons.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what is wrong? The output seems consistent with what is requested. Trying to understand why the answer is right/not right.