# Trying to write a script to find ORF from 6 different frames

Tags: command-line, regular-expression, bioinformatics

So basically, you have a sequence, say

```
AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

You need to find all the 'ORFs' in the sequence, an ORF is any region that starts with ATG and ends in TGA or TAA or TAG.

So, for example, in the above sequence, the ORFs are

```
AAAGCAT**ATGCTAG**CCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATAT**ATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG**
```

You'll notice, in the second ORF, there is an ATG inside the ORF, this happens when there isn't a TGA or TAA or TAG before it ends.

So yeah, basically that's the question. I know 2-3 ways of doing it on C++, but in terms of syntax in bash I have no clue.

I can't use any libraries or perl or anything like that, no special functions, just stuff like grep, awk, sed and loops.

Comment: What should be done with those sequences that are found? Marked by extra characters perhaps? Or written to stdout/a file, everything else deleted?

Comment: Unix text processing tools are not the best match for this, as they expect to work on "lines" of text, rather than one massive single line. Adding a newline after every TGA or TAA or TAG reduces the problem to "find the first ATG on each line, discarding any line without ATG".

Comment: @icarus okay how would I solve this problem using your method? Can you write it out? since I can think of the algorithm to do it but I actually don't know the syntax

Comment: What about nested ORFs? ORFs on different reading frames? If you have `ATGCATGATAGTATAA`, how many ORFs is that? `ATGCATGATAG` is one, `ATGATAGTATAA` is another, should we count both? What about the reverse strand? Most importantly, why in the _world_ are you doing this sort of thing in bash? Bash is a horrible tool for this, are you open to other suggestions?

Comment: @terdon My professor didn't allow me to do it on any other language.

Comment: @terdon yes, I need to consider the 3 reading frames, and forward and reverse strands

Comment: Sigh. My condolences, your professor is not helping you. I've been a bioinformatician for 15 years now and I have never done sequence manipulation in bash. But are you _sure_ they really expect you to code this in bash? Perhaps they just meant you need to use the command line?

Comment: I am 100% sure. I even wrote the script in C++ and ran it using terminal, but the professor said that he needs to see us writing the whole code in bash, like using stuff like grep awk sed etc.

Comment: @terdon sorry didnt tag you in above comment

Comment: Wait, what? grep awk and sed are not bash! Please clarify your requirements. You can do this in bash, I just wrote a script for it, but it's needlessly complicated. Are you now saying we can use non-bash things like awk or sed?

Comment: @terdon I don't quite know the difference between unix/bash etc, like what is the name of the language. It needs to be done in the command line.

Comment: The language is bash. Tools like `sed`, `awk` and `grep` have nothing to do with bash. Awk itself is a full programming language, so allowing you to use `awk` and not `perl` is absurd. They are the same class of thing. Even `sed` is Turing-complete! This sounds like you need to ask your professor to explain what they need. No sane bioinformatician would ever do this in pure bash. But, if you must, I have posted one approach below. It only deals with the forward strand, you can adapt it to deal with the reverse.

Comment: bash is just a (powerful) shell; it executes other powerful programs that are *built* to handle regular expressions and text processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` **if** you are using the GNU version of `grep`, which has the `-P` option for perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE).

Alternatively, you could use `pcregrep` (aka `pgrep`) by the author of the [PCRE](https://pcre.org/) library.   There's not much reason to use this these days unless you are using an old version of GNU grep, or a non-GNU grep, that doesn't suppoer the `-P` option and can't be upgraded or replaced.

e.g. (assuming that the sequences are in a file called `input.txt`):

```
$ grep -oP 'ATG.*?TA[AG]'  input.txt 
ATGCTAG
ATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

The `-o` option tells GNU grep to output only the matching text, not the entire line, and the `-P` tells it to use perl-compatible regular expressions.

Or, if you're using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -o 'ATG.*?TA[AG]'  input.txt 
ATGCTAG
ATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

The non-greedy `?` modifier in the regexp (`.*?`) ensures that it captures **ALL** matching patterns, not just the longest one.  In the context of regular expressions, "greedy" means "try to match as MUCH as possible" (the default), and "non-greedy" means "try to match as LITTLE as possible".

There's a good explanation of this at https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html. BTW, the rest of that site is a pretty good place to learn about regular expressions, with lots of tutorials and examples.

Note that most regular expression libraries **do not** implement non-greedy matches, it is a perl extension that has also been adopted by GNU grep.   and programs linked with [PCRE](https://pcre.org/), of course.

BTW, This is what the output would look like **without** the non-greedy modifier:

```
$ grep -oP 'ATG.*TA[AG]'  input.txt 
ATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

Comment: BTW, if you don't have `grep -P` or `pcregrep` (or perl), see this answer in [How to reduce the greediness of a regular expression in AWK?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388383/7696)

Comment: Surprisingly, the `?` also works with BSD `grep` (macOS), although it doesn't support PCRE, e.g. `grep -Eo 'ATG.*?(TGA|TA[AG])`.

Comment: @Freddy good to know. i didn't even try testing it on my freebsd vm - though it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The searching and matching to a regular expression can be done with `perl` (my favourite `sed` does not support the needed non-greedy regex(p) match):

```
# echo AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(ATG.*?TA[AG])(.*?)|\2\n|g'
ATGCTAG
ATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
AA
```

where the `perl` command prints the sequences you requested - and one last line with the rest of the line.  In order not to make the regular expression more complex this can easily be removed by hand or with `head`:

```
echo AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAGAA | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(ATG.*?TA[AG])(.*?)|\2\n|g' | head -n -1
ATGCTAG
ATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

These `echo` commands show the correct result for your sequence. If you wish to read the contents from a file, and send the result to a second file, do this:

```
cat original_file | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(ATG.*?TA[AG])(.*?)|\2\n|g' | head -n -1 > new_file
```

where `original_file` is your source file and `new_file` the target with filtered patterns.

The above uses `head` from GNU coreutils with the "-n -1" syntax.  If that does not work for you, please try

```
cat original_file | perl -pe 's|(.*?)(ATG.*?TA[AG])(.*?)|\2\n|g' | awk 'NR>1 {print prev} {prev=$0}' > new_file
```

Comment: Yes I want the output to be the sequences that match the criteria

Comment: I just realized I sound very stupid, can you show me the script you used to frame the  sequences with the x and y?

Comment: Okay I think I didn't explain my question well, I want the code to be getting any random sequence, and then outputting all the subsequences that start with ATG and end with TGA or TAA or TAG. I think your code only finds the answer to my specific string

Comment: @MridulaMMenon I have written an `echo command` but the perl command does the right thing for a file, too. I will modify the answer to make this more clear. Your question did not specify where data comes from or where the filtered data goes so I could only guess.

Comment: I used your  cat statement, and it said head: illegal line count -- -1

Comment: @MridulaMMenon It seems that your command `head` uses a different syntax to mine. Mine is from GNU coreutils and accepts the "-n -1" parameter. I changed my answer, please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in bash, but it's really not a good tool for it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash 

# Read the sequence into the variable $seq
seq=$1

## Check all three frames
for ((frame=0; frame<=3; frame++)); do
  ## Read the sequence in groups of 3
  for ((i=$frame;i<=${#seq};i+=3)); do
    ## The codon: three nucleotides starting from the current position.
    codon=${seq:i:3}
    ## set isORF to 1 if this is an ATG
    if [[ ${seq:i:3} = "ATG" ]]; then 
      isORF=1
    fi
    ## If we're in an ORF
    if [[ $isORF = 1 ]]; then
      ## Add this codon to the ORF's sequence
      ORF="${ORF}${codon}"
      ## Is this a STOP?
      if [[ ${seq:i:3} = "TGA" ||
            ${seq:i:3} = "TAA" ||
            ${seq:i:3} = "TAG" ]];
      then
        ## Print the ORF
        echo "ORF: $ORF"
        ## Set isORF to 0 and empty the ORF variable to repeat the process
        isORF=0
        ORF=""
    fi
  fi
  done
done
```

Save that as `foo.sh`, make it executable (`chmod a+x foo.sh`) and run it like this:

```
/path/to/foo.sh AAAGCATATGCTAGCCCGTATAGCGATACTAGCTATACGATATATATGATCAATGCCCGTATAG
```

Comment: You are a God send. I figured out how to do it for the reverse strand too. Now I just have to hope my prof doesn't look up what I turn in because then he will find this here.

Comment: @MridulaMMenon if your prof isn't an idiot they _will_ find this. And they will also tell you this is a stupid way of doing it. You are there to learn, just blindly copying answers you don't understand, especially bad answers like this one, will only harm you. Don't copy this, learn from it and adapt it.

Comment: My prof is a biochemist who doesn't know too much about programming. However, I wouldn't put it past them to look this up. I'll adapt it for sure, but the logic and the syntax will largely be the same. I'm worried that they will see the date this question was posted and connect the dots. Also, there isn't a question on the internet with this specific requirement so...

Comment: @MridulaMMenon well, you should have thought of that before you decided to ask strangers to do your work for you. It hadn't really occurred to me that you would just copy/paste this. If I had your professor's email, I would inform them myself. You should take this opportunity to _learn_, not just get a grade.

Comment: I can save you the trouble and tell the professor myself, I feel like I know how to get this done in other programming languages like C++ so I have achieved the objective, if my prof wants me to do it some particular way, while giving me bare minimal tools to do it, then it's an exercise in futility. The other classmates of mine just wrote a tediously long code without using loops so that beats the point of using bash but he has to be okay with that because he hasn't taught us enough syntax to write something like what you wrote which I would argue is more elegant

Comment: I properly understand your code and what you are doing, and I can now recreate it too. I wrote the code to reverse the string and fed it to your code also, I'm gonna have to study more syntax to be able to write the code as quickly as you did, but have I not 'learned' what you were meaning for me to learn? It's not just a grade, I learned a lot in the process of asking this question

Comment: do you think I could do this in a way where I find the start and stop, and if there number of characters between them is a multiple of 3, then it's an ORF?